# Spherical segment parameter estimation

Tags: regression, estimation

I am measuring metal holes drilled with a spherical drill using point laser. Since this is a hole, only about quarter of the points are visible:

### [image]

The method used is linear regression with Huber's estimation. Radius seems to be very sensitive to the height of the spherical segment:

[image: __]

---

Graph shows average radius [mm] dependent on the segment window height. Window is moved across the segment height using fixed step. Real radius is 14,0475 mm.

Is there any way to improve the regression stability and accuracy?